# ServiceStack: Disable escaping wildcards in typed expressions

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to generate a SQL LIKE query such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Users WHERE SearchField LIKE '%email:%domain.com%'
```

In OrmLite, the Contains statement escapes the % character generating this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Users WHERE upper("Users"."SearchField") like '%EMAIL:^%DOMAIN.COM%' escape '^'
```

Is it possible to disable the escaping (added in 4.0.19) or is there a better approach to generating the SQL statement?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrmLite's Typed API escapes wildcard strings so they're taken literally as a security precaution to prevent user input from returning sensitive data.

The easiest way is to use a custom SQL fragment, e.g:

```
q.Where("SearchField LIKE {0}", "%email:%domain.com%");
```

Otherwise it is possible to override [EscapeWildcards()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/9b69e300454632aa0eb8100370bf45a51a8d2edd/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs#L1437) in a custom DialectProvider (i.e. that inherits your preferred provider) to return the value without escaping the wildcards but that's an advanced customization I'd only consider if you're comfortable with maintaining a custom DialectProvider.